# Read XML file using Xml.Xpath and Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I am trying to read the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connection name="default">
  <Attribute name="server" value="localhost" />
  <Attribute name="database" value="mp" />
  <Attribute name="uid" value="root" />
  <Attribute name="password" value="m123" />
  <Attribute name="code" value="MK" />
</Connection>
```

With the following code:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("DBConnect.xml");
        var values = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Connection[@name='default']");
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            foreach (var att in item.Elements("Attribute"))
            {
                _server = att.Attribute("server").Value;
                _database = att.Attribute("database").Value;
                _uid = att.Attribute("uid").Value;
                _password = att.Attribute("password").Value;
                _code = att.Attribute("code").Value;
            }
        }
```

However, I don't seem to be getting the correct output. I am getting an error message which tells me `_server` is null. Any idea why? I don't think I am correctly referencing the XML attribute values I want to get a hold of.

Comment: Because your XPath uses `Mapping` and the element's name is `Connection`? When you say you don't seem to be getting the correct output, what output _are_ you getting?

Comment: @JLRishe - thanks, but its not telling me that `_server` is null. I commented it out and checked through each of the variables in the foreach loop that I am assigning the XML value to, and they are all coming up as null

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "output" you get.

Comment: "server" is the value of the attribute, not the attribute name

Comment: @steve16351 - thanks for clearing that up, how would I get the value of the server attribute name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One clean approach that you can use:

```
var values = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Connection[@name='default']")
                .Single()
                .Elements("Attribute")
                .ToDictionary(el => (string)el.Attribute("name"),
                              el => (string)el.Attribute("value"));

_server = values["server"];
_database = values["database"];
_uid = values["uid"];
_password = values["password"];
_code = values["code"];
```

`values` is an `IDictionary<string, string>`, so you can use it to retrieve any additional attributes that are added, without modifying the original LINQ code.

Comment: Actually like this answer more than the accepted answer. Both will work, but this one is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are looping through elements called `Attribute` and trying to find XML attributes there. Your logic would indicate that there should be all 5 XML attributes on each XML element called Attribute. Try using such code instead:

```
var values = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Connection[@name='default']");
_server = values.Elements("Attribute")   //look for an element called Attribute
             .Where(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "server")  //which has attribute name="server"
             .Single()    //there should be only single element
             .Attribute("value").Value; //get the value of attribute value
// Repeat that for all other attributes (_database, _uid, etc.)
```

Comment: I like this approach better

Comment: I keep getting `Replace with single call to Single(..)` at `values.Elements("Attribute").Where(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "server").Single()` - what does it mean?

Comment: It means that instead of `Where(...).Single()` you could use `Single(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "server")` which gives an identical functionality

Answer (score 1):

There is no attributes named "server", "database", "uid", "password" or "code". They're all values of the attributes named "name" which means you call Attribute("name") and not the value of it.
Ex.

```
var attrVal = attr.Attribute("name").Value;
if (attrVal == "server")
    _server = attrVal.Value;
// ... etc
```

In case the above doesn't work try this.

```
var attrVal = attr.Attribute("name").Value;
if (attrVal == "server")
    _server = attr.Attribute("value").Value;
// ... etc
```

Comment: @methuselah You shouldn't edit other people's answers to comment on their answer or add your own code. If you want to show us the code that you ultimately used, you can add it in an answer of your own.